# Favicon is not showing on Google Chrome

Tags: visualforce, favicon

I've created force.com site in salesforce. It has a different pages.
I've to show the "favicon" for Pages on tab.
I've inserted the below code for favicon & its work fine for Firefox, IE,

But Favicon is not showing on Google Chrome.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="!URLFOR($Resource.Logistic_Static_File, 'images/favicon.ico')}"/>`

Firefox Browser Screenshot:

[image]

Crome Browser : 
[image]

Please suggest the workaround.

Comment: Clear browser cache and or open in incognito.

Comment: @glls I've cleared the browser cache, but not getting success,

Comment: How about the favicon status code from thw chrome dev tools? What does it say?

Comment: @glls its not showing anything in browser console.

Comment: Not the console. The network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your favicon in settings, but not in page directly
[image]

Static resource:

[image]

Image:

[image]

Site settings:

[image]

Result:
Chrome

[image]

Mozilla:

[image]

Comment: I've put the "sit favorite icon" & remove from the code.  now I'm not able to see it any browser

Comment: @Amol try to clear cache

Comment: I've cleared the cache. but still I'm not able to see in any browser.